# For each combination of a set of variables in a list, calculating correlations between this combination and another variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, combinatorics

In R I want to generate correlation co-efficients by comparing 2 variables whilst also retaining a phylogenetic signal.

The initial way I thought to do this is not computationally efficient, and I think there is a much simpler, but I do not have the skills in R to do it.

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
+-------------------------------+-----+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|            Species            | OGT |  Domain  |       A       |      C       |      D       |      E       |      F       |      G       |      H       |      I       |      K       |       L       |      M       |      N       |      P       |      Q       |      R       |      S       |      T       |      V       |      W       |      Y       |
+-------------------------------+-----+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| Aeropyrum pernix              |  95 | Archaea  |  9.7659115711 | 0.6720465616 | 4.3895390781 | 7.6501943794 | 2.9344881615 | 8.8666657183 | 1.5011817208 | 5.6901432494 | 4.1428307243 | 11.0604191603 |   2.21143353 | 1.9387130928 | 5.1038552753 | 1.6855017182 | 7.7664358772 |  6.266067034 | 4.2052190807 | 9.2692433532 |  1.318690698 | 3.5614200159 |
| Argobacterium fabrum          |  26 | Bacteria | 11.5698896021 | 0.7985475923 | 5.5884500155 | 5.8165463343 | 4.0512504104 | 8.2643271309 | 2.0116736244 | 5.7962804605 | 3.8931525401 |  9.9250463349 | 2.5980609708 | 2.9846761128 | 4.7828063605 | 3.1262365491 | 6.5684282943 | 5.9454781844 | 5.3740045968 | 7.3382308193 | 1.2519739683 | 2.3149400984 |
| Anaeromyxobacter dehalogenans |  27 | Bacteria | 16.0337898849 | 0.8860252895 | 5.1368827707 | 6.1864992608 | 2.9730203513 | 9.3167603253 | 1.9360386851 |  2.940143349 | 2.3473650439 |  10.898494736 | 1.6343905351 | 1.5247123262 | 6.3580285706 | 2.4715303021 | 9.2639057482 | 4.1890063803 | 4.3992339725 | 8.3885969061 | 1.2890166336 | 1.8265589289 |
| Aquifex aeolicus              |  85 | Bacteria |  5.8730327277 |  0.795341216 | 4.3287799008 | 9.6746388172 | 5.1386954322 | 6.7148035486 | 1.5438364179 | 7.3358775924 | 9.4641440609 | 10.5736658776 | 1.9263080969 | 3.6183861236 | 4.0518679067 | 2.0493569604 | 4.9229955632 | 4.7976564501 | 4.2005259246 | 7.9169763709 | 0.9292167138 | 4.1438942987 |
| Archaeoglobus fulgidus        |  83 | Archaea  |  7.8742687687 | 1.1695110027 | 4.9165979364 | 8.9548767369 |  4.568636662 | 7.2640358917 | 1.4998752909 | 7.2472039919 | 6.8957233203 |  9.4826333048 | 2.6014466253 |  3.206476915 | 3.8419576418 | 1.7789787933 | 5.7572748236 | 5.4763351139 | 4.1490633048 | 8.6330814159 | 1.0325605451 | 3.6494619148 |
+-------------------------------+-----+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

What I want to do is, for each possible combination of the percentages within the 20 single letter columns (amino acids, so 10 million combinations). Is to calculate the correlation between each different combination and the OGT variable in the CSV.... (whilst retaining a phylogenetic signal)

My current code is this:

```
library(parallel)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ape)
library(geiger)
library(caper)



taxonomynex <- read.nexus("taxonomyforzeldospecies.nex")

zeldodata <- read.csv("COMPLETECOPYFORR.csv")

Species <- dput(zeldodata)

SpeciesLong <-
  Species %>%
  gather(protein, proportion,
         A:Y) %>%
  arrange(Species)


S <- unique(SpeciesLong$protein)


Scombi <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(S),
                        function(x) combn(S, x, FUN = paste0, collapse = "")))


joint_protein <- function(protein_combo, data){
  sum(data$proportion[vapply(data$protein,
                             grepl,
                             logical(1),
                             protein_combo)])
}


SplitSpecies <-
  split(SpeciesLong,
        SpeciesLong$Species)

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)

clusterExport(cl, c("Scombi", "joint_protein"))


SpeciesAggregate <-
  parLapply(cl,
            X = SplitSpecies,
            fun = function(data){
              X <- lapply(Scombi,
                          joint_protein,
                          data)
              names(X) <- Scombi
              as.data.frame(X)
            })
Species <- cbind(Species, SpeciesAggregate)
```

`

Which attempts to feed in each combination into memory and then calculate the sum of each proportion of each of the acids, but this takes forever to finish and crashes before completion.

I think it would be better to feed in correlation co-efficents into a vector, and then just print out the relative co-efficients of each different combination for each species, but I don't know the best way of doing this in R.

I also aim to retain a phylogenetic signal using the ape package using something along the lines of this:

```
pglsModel <- gls(OGT ~ AminoAcidCombination, correlation = corBrownian(phy = taxonomynex),
    data = zeldodata, method = "ML")
summary(pglsModel)
```

Apologies for how unclear this is, if anyone has any advice, much appreciated!

Edit: [Link to taxonomyforzeldospecies.nex](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BzahGhabTjKVWVjO9b4M0l_PyVjBaLaL/view?usp=sharing)

Output from dput(Zeldodata):

```
  1              Species              OGT    Domain          A              C              D              E              F              G              H              I              K               L              M              N              P              Q              R              S              T              V              W              Y        
     ------------------------------- ----- ---------- --------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -------------- 
  2   Aeropyrum pernix                 95   Archaea     9.7659115711   0.6720465616   4.3895390781   7.6501943794   2.9344881615   8.8666657183   1.5011817208   5.6901432494   4.1428307243   11.0604191603     2.21143353   1.9387130928   5.1038552753   1.6855017182   7.7664358772    6.266067034   4.2052190807   9.2692433532    1.318690698   3.5614200159  
  3   Argobacterium fabrum             26   Bacteria   11.5698896021   0.7985475923   5.5884500155   5.8165463343   4.0512504104   8.2643271309   2.0116736244   5.7962804605   3.8931525401    9.9250463349   2.5980609708   2.9846761128   4.7828063605   3.1262365491   6.5684282943   5.9454781844   5.3740045968   7.3382308193   1.2519739683   2.3149400984  
  4   Anaeromyxobacter dehalogenans    27   Bacteria   16.0337898849   0.8860252895   5.1368827707   6.1864992608   2.9730203513   9.3167603253   1.9360386851    2.940143349   2.3473650439    10.898494736   1.6343905351   1.5247123262   6.3580285706   2.4715303021   9.2639057482   4.1890063803   4.3992339725   8.3885969061   1.2890166336   1.8265589289  
  5   Aquifex aeolicus                 85   Bacteria    5.8730327277    0.795341216   4.3287799008   9.6746388172   5.1386954322   6.7148035486   1.5438364179   7.3358775924   9.4641440609   10.5736658776   1.9263080969   3.6183861236   4.0518679067   2.0493569604   4.9229955632   4.7976564501   4.2005259246   7.9169763709   0.9292167138   4.1438942987  
  6   Archaeoglobus fulgidus           83   Archaea     7.8742687687   1.1695110027   4.9165979364   8.9548767369    4.568636662   7.2640358917   1.4998752909   7.2472039919   6.8957233203    9.4826333048   2.6014466253    3.206476915   3.8419576418   1.7789787933   5.7572748236   5.4763351139   4.1490633048   8.6330814159   1.0325605451   3.6494619148
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to `taxonomyforzeldospecies.nex` and paste the output of `dput(zeldodata)`?

Comment: Yep! Edited the main post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will give you a long data frame with each combination and sum per `Species` (takes about 35 seconds on my machine)...

```
zeldodata <- 
  Species %>%
  gather(protein, proportion, A:Y) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(combo = sapply(1:n(), function(i) combn(protein, i, FUN = paste0, collapse = ""))) %>% 
  mutate(sum = sapply(1:n(), function(i) combn(proportion, i, FUN = sum))) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  select(-protein, -proportion)
```

---

an example of calculating each species separately and saving the data to disk before reading each one in and combining them...

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# read in CSV file
zeldodata <-
  read_delim(
    delim = "|",
    trim_ws = TRUE,
    col_names = TRUE,
    col_types = "cicdddddddddddddddddddd", 
    file = "Species                       | OGT |  Domain  |       A       |      C       |      D       |      E       |      F       |      G       |      H       |      I       |      K       |       L       |      M       |      N       |      P       |      Q       |      R       |      S       |      T       |      V       |      W       |      Y
    Aeropyrum pernix              |  95 | Archaea  |  9.7659115711 | 0.6720465616 | 4.3895390781 | 7.6501943794 | 2.9344881615 | 8.8666657183 | 1.5011817208 | 5.6901432494 | 4.1428307243 | 11.0604191603 |   2.21143353 | 1.9387130928 | 5.1038552753 | 1.6855017182 | 7.7664358772 |  6.266067034 | 4.2052190807 | 9.2692433532 |  1.318690698 | 3.5614200159
    Argobacterium fabrum          |  26 | Bacteria | 11.5698896021 | 0.7985475923 | 5.5884500155 | 5.8165463343 | 4.0512504104 | 8.2643271309 | 2.0116736244 | 5.7962804605 | 3.8931525401 |  9.9250463349 | 2.5980609708 | 2.9846761128 | 4.7828063605 | 3.1262365491 | 6.5684282943 | 5.9454781844 | 5.3740045968 | 7.3382308193 | 1.2519739683 | 2.3149400984
    Anaeromyxobacter dehalogenans |  27 | Bacteria | 16.0337898849 | 0.8860252895 | 5.1368827707 | 6.1864992608 | 2.9730203513 | 9.3167603253 | 1.9360386851 |  2.940143349 | 2.3473650439 |  10.898494736 | 1.6343905351 | 1.5247123262 | 6.3580285706 | 2.4715303021 | 9.2639057482 | 4.1890063803 | 4.3992339725 | 8.3885969061 | 1.2890166336 | 1.8265589289
    Aquifex aeolicus              |  85 | Bacteria |  5.8730327277 |  0.795341216 | 4.3287799008 | 9.6746388172 | 5.1386954322 | 6.7148035486 | 1.5438364179 | 7.3358775924 | 9.4641440609 | 10.5736658776 | 1.9263080969 | 3.6183861236 | 4.0518679067 | 2.0493569604 | 4.9229955632 | 4.7976564501 | 4.2005259246 | 7.9169763709 | 0.9292167138 | 4.1438942987
    Archaeoglobus fulgidus        |  83 | Archaea  |  7.8742687687 | 1.1695110027 | 4.9165979364 | 8.9548767369 |  4.568636662 | 7.2640358917 | 1.4998752909 | 7.2472039919 | 6.8957233203 |  9.4826333048 | 2.6014466253 |  3.206476915 | 3.8419576418 | 1.7789787933 | 5.7572748236 | 5.4763351139 | 4.1490633048 | 8.6330814159 | 1.0325605451 | 3.6494619148"
  )

# save an RDS file for each species
for(species in unique(zeldodata$Species)) {
  zeldodata %>%
    filter(Species == species) %>% 
    gather(protein, proportion, A:Y) %>%
    mutate(combo = sapply(1:n(), function(i) combn(protein, i, FUN = paste0, collapse = ""))) %>% 
    mutate(sum = sapply(1:n(), function(i) combn(proportion, i, FUN = sum))) %>% 
    unnest() %>% 
    select(-protein, -proportion) %>% 
    saveRDS(file = paste0(species, ".RDS"))
}

# read in and combine all the RDS files
zeldodata <- 
  list.files(pattern = "\\.RDS") %>%
  map(read_rds) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message each time and R crashes, my data-file is a lot bigger than the example I gave, it's 204 species rather than just 5, is there anyway to do this and just print to a dataframe rather than holding it all in memory?

Comment: Seeing the error message you get would probably be useful. It obviously will take a lot longer if you have significantly more species to calculate. You could possibly run a loop through each species and calculate the values then save the resulting data.frame to disk... then load and merge each species' data.frame up to as much memory as your machine can handle.

Comment: Yep sorry, it wouldn't let me copy and paste as R crashed, and it takes several hours so I will post it as soon as it crashes again!

What would be the best way of saving the intermediate data-frames to disk

Comment: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: invalid 'ncol' value (too large or NA).
In addition: Warning message:
In combn(protein, i, FUN = paste0, collapse = "") :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

Comment: added an example of calculating each species separately and saving to disk, then reading in each file and combining them

Comment: Could I just replace 'file = "..." with the csv file I have?

Comment: actually, probably no since what you posted was data delimited by a "|" rather than data delimited by ","

Comment: Got it, but changing the delim = to ',' should change that! Thanks!

Comment: It's chugging away with:

`zeldodata <-
  read_delim(
    delim = ",",
    trim_ws = TRUE,
    col_names = TRUE,
    col_types = "cicdddddddddddddddddddd", 
    file = "COMPLETECOPYFORR.csv"`

At the moment, but if that doesn't work I'll try `read_csv()`